# How to access (probably unavailable) array indexes elegantly in Angular templates?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

Let's say I have an array of objects:

```
public arr: {val: string}[] = [];
```

Now I want to access the first object, *but the array can be **empty** also*.

The compiler guesses that this is OK, but it will fail during runtime - obviously:

```
<app-comp [value]="arr[0].val"></app-comp>
<div>{{ arr[0}.val }}</div>
```

Using the `?.` operator works, but it will throw a warning:

```
<app-comp [value]="arr[0]?.val"></app-comp>
<div>{{ arr[0}?.val }}</div>
```

> Warning NG8107: The left side of this optional chain operation does not include 'null' or 'undefined' in its type, therefore the '?.' operator can be replaced with the '.' operator

Now the solution that works for me is this:

```
<app-comp [value]="arr[0] && arr[0].val"></app-comp>
<div>{{ arr[0] && arr[0].val }}</div>
```

But it bloats the template. *Is there a more elegant solution to this problem?*

Using `*ngIf` will only work sometimes, when `<app-comp>` or the `<div>` parent can be omitted. Which will not always be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-container` tag. This tag does not add any element and any parent elements will not be removed.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="arr[0]; let obj">
  <app-comp [value]="obj.val"></app-comp>
  <div>{{ obj.val }}</div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Yeah, that will work too. But this also clutters the template, don't you think? Is this more robust than my current solution?

Comment: I have suggested this answer because this is less redundant.  And your solution passes `undefined` to `app-comp` when `arr` is empty. Is it OK?

Comment: True that. In this case it's ok, but you got a point with `undefined`. However it's still not possible to use when `app-comp` or `div` are required.